# module feeder help pubdate

Tags: php, rss, prestashop, feed

Prestashop 1.7.5.2
for module feeder https://github.com/PrestaShop/feeder

I would to add the date of add or update of products ; I've added this code:

```php
$date = date('r', strtotime($product['date_add']); 
echo '<pubdate>'.$date.'</pubdate>';
```

but it doens't work with 500 error
instead this simple code:

```php
$pubDate = date('r', time()); 
echo "<pubDate>$pubDate</pubDate>";
```

works, but without the add date of products.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Error 500 just means the error is being hidden to visitors and you need to find it in the logs. In any case, the code you've shared won't even run due to a missing bracket.

Comment: Sorry, where are the missing bracket?

Comment: Oh damn, the solution is:

    $date = date('r', strtotime($product['date_add'])); 
echo '<pubdate>'.$date.'</pubdate>';

I was lost the last bracket.

Comment: PHP can warn you about these kind of issues, there's no need to wonder for several hours. Please make sure you enable full [error reporting](https://phptherightway.com/#development).